# Acer Swift SF314-43 model laptop with the Ubuntu 22.04 operating system. camera is not functioning, and I'm receiving a "no device found"

Tags: 22.04, acer, camera, selinux

I'm using an Acer Swift SF314-43 model laptop with the Ubuntu 22.04 operating system. The issue I'm encountering is that my camera is not functioning, and I'm receiving a

> no device found

error. The output of `lsusb` is:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:0c72 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN: Fingerprint 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04ca:3802 Lite-On Technology Corp. Wireless_Device 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub.
```

Can you please assist me in resolving this problem?

Comment: The `lsusb` output shows that the device is not detected. A quick [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=Acer+Swift+SF314-43+camera+not+detected) reveals that this seems to be a common problem. I have no answer, though.

Comment: sudo dmesg | grep -i cable | grep -i bad

Comment: v4l2-ctl --list-devices

Comment: Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting. I'm getting this after running this command